# calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath when i uitableviewcell is swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am using [ABMenuTableViewCell](https://github.com/alexbumbu/ABMenuTableViewCell)  `tableview controller` in my application.
I want to call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` when i swipe a cell.

Right now `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` only execute when i tap on a cell, i want to call it even when i swipe it. here is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `cellforRowAtIndexPath` methods code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        UILabel *likes;
        UILabel *downloads;
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        ABMenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[ABMenuTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            arrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"acc_arrow_back.png"]];
            arrow.frame = CGRectMake(300, 50, 5, 12);
            arrow.image = [arrow.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [arrow setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:arrow];

UIImageView *likes_img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"social.png"]];
            likes_img.frame = CGRectMake(15, 80, 15, 15);
            likes_img.image = [likes_img.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [likes_img setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:likes_img];

            likes =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(33, 78, 80, 20)];
            likes.tag = 1001;    // set a tag for this View so you can get at it later
            likes.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
            likes.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0f];
            likes.text=[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmllikes];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:likes];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

            UIImageView *downloads_img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.png"]];
            downloads_img.frame = CGRectMake(55, 79, 15, 15);
            downloads_img.image = [downloads_img.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
            [downloads_img setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(191/255.0) green:(2/255.0) blue:(6/255.0) alpha:1]];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:downloads_img];

            downloads =[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(73, 78, 80, 20)];
            downloads.tag = 1002;    // set a tag for this View so you can get at it later
            downloads.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
            downloads.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0f];
            downloads.text=[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmldownloads];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:downloads];
            cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        }
        else
        {
            // use viewWithTag to find lblNombre in the re-usable cell.contentView
            likes = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
            downloads = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1002];

        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlsinger];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmltitle];
        // custom menu view
        NSString *nibName = @"ABCellMailStyleMenuView";
        ABCellMenuView *menuView = [ABCellMenuView initWithNib:nibName bundle:nil];
        menuView.delegate = self;
        menuView.indexPath = indexPath;
        cell.rightMenuView = menuView;
        return cell;
}


   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
   }
```

and these are the methods in cell class - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer and - (void)swipeGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture and UIPanGestureRecognizer *_swipeGesture;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `UISwipeGesture`. you can achieve by two way. adding `UISwipeGesture` to `UITableViewCell` or `UITableView`. Here i am  only explain adding `UISwipeGesture` on `UITableView` because of in this case you need to add `UISwipeGesture` single time.

How to add `UISwipeGesture` in `UITableView`.

```
//Add a left swipe gesture recognizer
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                  action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];

    //Add a right swipe gesture recognizer
    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                        action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
```

And here is selector method of `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`. where you have `indexPath` that will give you `index` of your `Image` `Array`.

```
-(void)didSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

  if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint swipeLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:swipeLocation];


        [imageArray removedObjectAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath.row];
        [tableView reloadData];
  }
```

Here i am consider `imageArray` is your `array of images`.

Hope this help you.

Comment: let me know if you stuck any where.

Comment: tried this one but still isn't working i even put a nslog in didSwipe but it didn't even called.

Comment: have you added `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` in your `UItableView`?

Comment: in my storyboard tight? yes i did that

Comment: i don't know weather problem with binding or what. i would like to give suggestion that you can add UISwipeGesture in you viewDidLoad method programatically as like above code. and check that its selector method is called or not?

Comment: have you  set `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` delegate method to `self`.? like recognizer.delegate = self;

Comment: yes i did that but still not calling selector method. Thanks

Comment: i implemented UISwipeGestureRecognizer in viewdidload but still no change

Comment: i think `ABMenuTableViewCell` already have `UIPanGestureRecognizer` implemented so please check that while swiping is it UIPanGesture selector method is called or not?

Comment: these method there  - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer  and - (void)swipeGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture and     UIPanGestureRecognizer *_swipeGesture;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76105/discussion-between-vix-hunk-and-none).

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply gesture on UITableView and find out the cell by using indexPathForRowAtPoint.

follow this link - http://jademind.com/blog/posts/swipe-gestures-on-uitableview/

Comment: I just tried left and right gesture over the tableview cell and its working fine for me. I have also created public repository for same. You can check the demo app https://github.com/Nilesh-Mahajan/SwitpeGestureTableView